# How do I keep Xilinx XST from merging nets from my design?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, xilinx

I'm asking and answering this question so that I can find it again in the future...

How do I  keep XST from merging two logically equivalent nets into one (which normally is a good idea to save resources, but may not be a good idea from a timing view)?

I have a design with 2 counters that are driven by the same clk. XST merged the lowest bit of the counters into one counter, but this is a problem, because the counters need to be separated in the design due to IOB placement constraints. I need the counters (specifically the lowest bit of the counter) to be distinct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set 2 constraints on the net in your RTL. Check the synthesis report for your net to make sure that XST did what you wanted.

In Verilog

```
(* equivalent_register_removal="no" *)
(* keep="true" *)
reg  signal_name ;
```

In VHDL

```
signal signal_name  : std_logic;
attribute equivalent_register_removal: string;   
attribute equivalent_register_removal of signal_name : signal is "no";
attribute keep:string;
attribute keep of signal_name :signal is "true";
```

Comment: As an important note, different synthesis tools have different attribute names to perform the same function. So if, for example, you were using Synopsys Synplify for synthesis instead, you would need differently named attributes. The answer here applies to XST.